# Getting values between quotes

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get the value between quotes with an RegEx

for example I want to find all the parameters from the function test

```
<html>
   test("bla");
   print("foo");
   test("moo");
</html>
```

The result must be { "bla", "moo" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the args to `test`, you'll need to include that in the regex:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    bool first = true;
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(html, @"test\((""[^\""]*\"")\)"))
    {
        if(first) {first = false;}
        else {sb.Append(',');}
        sb.Append(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
    sb.Append('}');
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

From the question, I am using quote detection here.

Alternatively - if you just want the values:

```
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(html, @"test\(""([^\""]*)\""\)"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
```

The main change here is that the group is now inside the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

edit: Removed old code and made a linq version...

```
    var array = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(inText, "\"\\w+?\"")
                 select m.Groups[0].Value).ToArray();

    string json = string.Format("{{{0}}}", string.Join(",", array));
```