# How to get data between certain quotes

Tags: c#

```
string s  = "<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""/stepcarousel.js""></script>"
```

How can I get the data inside the `src` attribute?

Means i want /stepcarousel.js in messagebox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting values between quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286971/getting-values-between-quotes)

Comment: I guss you dont know how to read the question Mr Disappointment

Comment: What's that with the double double "" quotes? Is that valid code at all?

Comment: @Martin: It's a way to escape quotes. The whole string should be prefixed with a `@` though.

Comment: @Jason: An `@` is missing here, that's what I thought, too. That or some `\"`...

Comment: @MoizKachwala I guess Mr Disappointment strongly objects the idea of parsing text that could be treated as Xml and easily queried using xpath.

Comment: That being said, a single XML tag without nesting is definitely regular, thus can be easily done with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, come on.

```
string s = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/stepcarousel.js\"></script>";
int startIndex = s.IndexOf("src=\"") + "src=\"".Length;
int endIndex = s.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
string src = s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason.. that's was perfect what i wanted.. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/stepcarousel.js\"></script>");
string src = doc.SelectSingleNode("//script/@src").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here:

```
s.Substring(36, 17);
```

Seriously, though, just find `src="`:

```
int i = s.IndexOf("src=\"");
s.Substring(i + 5, s.IndexOf('"', i + 5) - i - 5);
```